# How Can I Correct This Java Infinite Random Number Generation?

Tags: java, random

I'm writing a game of Battleships for a class, and i'm working on the AI for it right now. It works perfect sometimes, but sometimes when it's guessing a random number, it keeps guessing it infinitely and I have no idea why. I currently have it guess coordinates based on the size of the smallest alive ship. 
I'm also checking if the coordinate was guessed already, and i'm assuming this is where the problem is. g2 is a two dimensional array containing whether guesses have been hits or misses. ~ represents unguessed.

This is what my grid looks like when it's stuck in loop.

```
\  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
------------------------------
a| M  ~  M  ~  H  H  H  H  M  ~ 
b| ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~ 
c| M  ~  M  ~  M  ~  M  ~  M  ~ 
d| ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~ 
e| M  ~  M  ~  M  ~  M  ~  M  ~ 
f| ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~ 
g| M  ~  M  ~  M  ~  M  ~  M  ~ 
h| ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~ 
i| M  ~  M  ~  M  ~  M  ~  M  ~ 
j| ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~
```

This is my loop where it picks it's coordinate.

```
while (true) {
            a = rn.nextInt(10);
            while (a % parity != 0) {
                a++;
                if (a > 9)
                    a = 0;
            }
            n = rn.nextInt(10);
            while (n % parity != 0) {
                n++;
                if (n > 9)
                    n = 0;
            }

                if (g2[a][n] == '~') { //ensures coordinate has not been guessed already
                    break;
                } 
            System.out.println((let[a]) + "" + n); //displays coordinate if guessed already
        }
```

As requested, here's a larger code snippet for context.
lastHit is the coordinates of the last ship hit during this Hit Mode.
firstHit is the coordinate of the first hit this Hit mode.

Also, when I call these from my main game loop, I use:

```
p1.fireResult(p2.fireUpon(p1.fire()));
```

Where p1 and p2 are Player objects.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class AIPlayer_ndk22 implements Player {
Random rn = new Random();
char[] let = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j' };
int n;
int a;
char[][] g1 = new char[10][10];
char[][] g2 = new char[10][10];
int[] shipHits = new int[5];
Coordinate last;
Coordinate lastHit, firstHit;
boolean hitModechan = false;
int parity = 2, miss = 0;

/**
* This player is being fired upon. Given a coordinate, updates board(s) accordingly.
* 
* @param x - the coordinate that is being fired upon
* @return M for miss, otherwise the ship's char representation
*/
public char fireUpon(Coordinate c) {
    if (g1[c.x][c.y] == '~') {
        return 'M';
    } else {
        return g1[c.x][c.y];
    }
}

/**
* Returns a coordinate that this player wishes to guess.
* 
* 
* @return A coordinate object 
*/
public Coordinate fire() {
    Coordinate coords;
    if (!hitModechan) {
        while (true) {
            a = rn.nextInt(10);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch(Exception e){}
            while (a % parity != 0) {
                a++;
                if (a > 9)
                    a = 0;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch(Exception e){}
            n = rn.nextInt(10);
            while (n % parity != 0) {
                n++;
                if (n > 9)
                    n = 0;
            }

                if (g2[a][n] == '~') { //ensures coordinate has not been guessed already
                    break;
                } 
            System.out.print((let[a]) + "" + n + " ");
            System.out.println(g2[a][n]);
        }
    } else {
        if (miss == 0) {
            if (lastHit.x > 0 && g2[(lastHit.x) - 1][lastHit.y] == '~') {
                a = (lastHit.x) - 1;
                n = lastHit.y;
            } else {
                miss++;
            }
        }
        if (miss == 1) {
            if (lastHit.y < 9 && g2[(lastHit.x)][lastHit.y + 1] == '~') {
                a = lastHit.x;
                n = (lastHit.y) + 1;
            } else
                miss++;
        }
        if (miss == 2) {
            if (lastHit.y > 0 && g2[(lastHit.x)][lastHit.y - 1] == '~') {
                a = lastHit.x;
                n = (lastHit.y) - 1;
            } else
                miss++;
        }
        if (miss == 3) {
            if (lastHit.x < 9 && g2[(lastHit.x) + 1][lastHit.y] == '~') {
                a = (lastHit.x) + 1;
                n = lastHit.y;
            } else
                miss++;
        }
        if (miss == 4) {
            miss = 0;
            if (miss == 0) {
                if (firstHit.x > 0 && g2[(firstHit.x) - 1][firstHit.y] == '~') {
                    a = (firstHit.x) - 1;
                    n = firstHit.y;
                } else {
                    miss++;
                }
            }
            if (miss == 1) {
                if (firstHit.y < 9 && g2[(firstHit.x)][firstHit.y + 1] == '~') {
                    a = firstHit.x;
                    n = (firstHit.y) + 1;
                } else
                    miss++;
            }
            if (miss == 2) {
                if (firstHit.y > 0 && g2[(firstHit.x)][firstHit.y - 1] == '~') {
                    a = firstHit.x;
                    n = (firstHit.y) - 1;
                } else
                    miss++;
            }
            if (miss == 3) {
                if (firstHit.x < 9 && g2[(firstHit.x) + 1][firstHit.y] == '~') {
                    a = (firstHit.x) + 1;
                    n = firstHit.y;
                }
            } else {
                hitModechan = false;
                while (true) {
                    a = rn.nextInt(10);
                    while (a % parity != 0) {
                        a++;
                        if (a > 9)
                            a = 0;
                    }
                    n = rn.nextInt(10);
                    while (n % parity != 0) {
                        n++;
                        if (n > 9)
                            n = 0;
                    }
                    if (g2[a][n] == '~') { //ensures coordinate has not been guessed already
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("AI guesses at: %c%d\n", let[a], n);
    coords = new Coordinate(a, n);
    last = coords;
    return coords;
}

/**
* Callback method to notify player whether last fire() attempt was successful or not.
*  
* @param result 'M' if the last fire() resulted in a miss, otherwise the character code of the ship
*/
public void fireResult(char result) {
    if (result == 'M') {
        g2[last.x][last.y] = 'M';
        System.out.println("AI Miss");
        if (hitModechan) {
            miss++;
            if (miss == 4) {
                lastHit = firstHit;
                miss = 0;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (!hitModechan) {
            firstHit = new Coordinate(last.x, last.y);
            lastHit = firstHit;
            hitModechan = true;
        } else {
            miss = 0;
            lastHit = new Coordinate(last.x, last.y);
        }
        g2[last.x][last.y] = 'H';
        System.out.println("AI Hit");
        if (result == 'P') {
            shipHits[0]++;
            if (shipHits[0] == 2) {
                System.out.println("Patrol Boat Sunk.");
                hitModechan = false;
                parity = 3;
            }
        } else if (result == 'S') {
            shipHits[1]++;
            if (shipHits[1] == 3) {
                System.out.println("Submarine Sunk.");
                hitModechan = false;
                if (shipHits[2] == 3 && shipHits[0] == 2) {
                    parity = 4;
                }
            }
        } else if (result == 'D') {
            shipHits[2]++;
            if (shipHits[2] == 3) {
                System.out.println("Destroyer Sunk.");
                hitModechan = false;
            }
        } else if (result == 'B') {
            shipHits[3]++;
            if (shipHits[3] == 4) {
                System.out.println("Battleship Sunk.");
                hitModechan = false;
            }
        } else {
            shipHits[4]++;
            if (shipHits[4] == 5) {
                System.out.println("Carrier Sunk.");
                hitModechan = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe g2[a][n] == '~' is never true. Check it.

Comment: Or you're not updating g2 correctly, so even after it guesses a coordinate, g2 for that coordinate is still '~'.

Comment: You're trying to match the guess to the length of the ship through by modding with `parity`?

Comment: What is `parity` here?

Comment: You should add more of your code, otherwise we're just blindly guessing what could be wrong.

Comment: @DavidWallace the length of the smallest ship that's alive.

Comment: what does the class look like that object reference rn calls?

Comment: If you've got a 10x10 board, just keep a list of all unused coordinates.  The code to ensure that you don't pick a dupe, even once you get it right, will take more space than the list of coordinates.

Comment: If `parity` is ever more than 9, you'll just get (0,0) over and over.  Is that what's happening?  Maybe you could tell us what `parity` equals in the cases when you get this problem.

Comment: @MikeSamuel so instead of having it guess a random x and a random y, have it pick a random coordinate from the list of unused?

Comment: @DavidWallace I've checked parity, I even kept it at 2 to check if it was the problem. Also, I print out the coordinate, it correctly gives me random coordinates each time (e.g. e1 f7 etc)

Comment: OK, so just to clarify - are you saying that `System.out.println((let[a]) + "" + n);` prints the same coordinates repeatedly, without breaking out of the loop?  Or are you saying that you always break out of the loop with the same value?

Comment: Ok so it's not a problem with parity, but a problem with my implementation of it. It's spacing out its guesses too much so that places where ships are aren't guessed. See edited question for what the grid looks like when stuck in loop.
@DavidWallace It prints out different coordinates each time it loops.

Comment: @NicholasKunze, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with my implementation of parity.
Fixed code:

```
while (true) {
            a = rn.nextInt(10);
            /*while (a % parity != 0) {
                a++;
                if (a > 9)
                    a = 0;
            }*/
            n = rn.nextInt(10);
            while ((n + a)% parity != 0) {
                n++;
                if (n > 9)
                    n = 0;
            }

                if (g2[a][n] == '~') { //ensures coordinate has not been guessed already
                    break;
                } 
            System.out.print((let[a]) + "" + n + " ");
            System.out.println(g2[a][n]);
            printBoard();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion.  Generate a list of all coordinates.  Shuffle the list into random order.  Now pick coordinates off the list in their shuffled order.  Check each coordinate for a "~" on the main grid after you pull it off the list.

A shuffled list guarantees each coordinate is only picked once.